# Get network printer printing history with SNMP OID commands

Tags: c#, snmp, network-printers, oid

I need some help with network printers. I would like to make a database with printed jobs, but i cant find any info on the internet. I use SNMP to get the counter, but i did'nt found any OID command to get the printed job's name. Any idea how can i make it? The printer is a HP p4015n network printer.

Comment: You are best to start by doing a full snmp walk on the device to see what it offers; not all devices will do all things. From a linux machine run `snmpwalk -v2c -c public <ip of printer> .1.3 >> printer-walk.txt` then browse the text file it makes. I'll check one of my HP machines tomorrow when I'm back in the office.

Comment: Maybe you can find the printed job's name in the  HP-LASERJET-COMMON-MIB.

Answer (score 0):

It's old question, but it might help someone else.

get (Current) JobID using this OID: .1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.3.9.4.2.1.1.6.2.1.1.0
use this OID to get JobName: .1.3.6.1.4.1.11.2.3.9.4.2.1.1.6.5.1.{0}.0
(replace {0} with JobID from first step)